# How to save metadata into database from a rake file (rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, metadata

I am building a script to scrape data from a website. You can see the full code here: [Undefined method 'click' for nil:NilClass (Mechanize)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786256/undefined-method-click-for-nilnilclass-mechanize/32786542#32786542)

Anyways, I have trouble to save this metadata into the database:

```
members = member_links.map do |link|

member = link.click
name = member.search('title').text.split('|')[0]
institution = member.search('td~ td+ td').text.split(':')[0]
dob = member.search('.birthdate').text.strip[1..4]

{
  name: name.strip,
  institution: institution.strip,
  dob: dob,
  bio: bio
}
end
```

Thus, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have any ActiveRecord models so far?

Comment: @AlexeyShein Yes. I have an ActiveRecord model named datum. It consist the field like name, institution, dob, bio etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it should be as simple as:

```
Datum.create!(
  name: name.strip,
  institution: institution.strip,
  dob: dob,
  bio: bio
)
```

This is very basic Rails knowledge, make sure you've read [Active Record Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) guide.