# i want to scrape some website using ruby and mechanize gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, web-scraping

i want to scrape some website, which contain pagination.

for example http://somesite.com/page/

i want scrape each post in each pagination.

so, in page/1 , there are about 5 posts.

how to scrape each data inside each pagination? until the end page?

i've search and research, and i found 2 similar question, but im still confuse it..

here >>

[first way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786256/undefined-method-click-for-nilnilclass-mechanize)

[second way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880921/use-ruby-mechanize-to-scrape-all-successive-pages)

any idea how to combine it?

thanks before

Comment: [you can read this post](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/web-crawling/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **have** to use mechanize gems? I'd strongly recommend you to use [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/). It's very simple and easy to use.

You can have a loop that fetch the pages and stop when you can't find the page.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
pages_count = 1
loop do
    @html = Nokogiri::HTML(open("somepage.com/#{pages_count}"))
    ...
    pages_count = pages_count + 1
end
```

Comment: can you help me about it?

Comment: How can I help you?

Comment: help me to find the solutions..

Comment: The snippet I posted should guide you on how to scrape multiple indexed-by-url pages. You just have to do the scraping in the loop block and change the url. You have to be more accurate on your doubts so we can help you better

Comment: at this case, i need .click methode to open each posts, because each post has preview thumbnail.

so how to make it click by self, and then scrape the data ? because its little bit difficult

Comment: Can you provide us the link for the real site? Maybe there's a better alternative. I've built lots of scrappers and never had to click anything.

Comment: Hmmm, this is the site, http://oploverz.in < its just for example.. If you do, we can chat by email, here my email: andadj@gmail.com

Comment: I need scrape each post which contain such image, links download, timestamp, and etc. Can you give me an example from your code? Similar site, it will be much more helpfull.